# Spring Boot 3 and JSP application won't run as standalone

Tags: spring-boot, jsp, tomcat

I upgraded a JSP application to Spring Boot 3 and now it won't start when running as a standalone application.

If I start the application using `gradle bootRun` it runs fine.

When runing it using `java -jar oldnewjspapp.war` I get the following stacktrace:

```
ERROR 7082 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start web server
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.onRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:164) ~[spring-boot-3.0.1.jar!/:3.0.1]
...
Caused by: org.springframework.boot.web.server.WebServerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.initialize(TomcatWebServer.java:142) ~[spring-boot-3.0.1.jar!/:3.0.1]
...
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: zip file closed
    at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile.ensureOpen(ZipFile.java:831) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile.getManifestName(ZipFile.java:1057) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile$1.getManifestName(ZipFile.java:1100) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.jar.JarFile.getManEntry(JarFile.java:937) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.jar.JarFile.checkForSpecialAttributes(JarFile.java:1000) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.jar.JarFile.isMultiRelease(JarFile.java:389) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.JarFileUrlJar.<init>(JarFileUrlJar.java:68) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.4.jar!/:na]
```

Does anyone have a solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spring Boot 3 JSP support is broken:

- [Spring boot app's .jar not working (issue with tomcat-embed-jasper)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74913190/spring-boot-apps-jar-not-working-issue-with-tomcat-embed-jasper)
- https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/33633
- https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/32106

The alternatives are:

1. downgrade your Spring Boot version
2. extract the war contents and run it that way
3. generate a regular war (`gradle war`) and publish it in your favourite web server
4. turn off the support for [Multi-Release JAR Files](https://openjdk.org/jeps/238) (this feature is present in Java since release 9): `java -Djdk.util.jar.enableMultiRelease=false -jar oldnewjspapp.war`

Comment: IMO, a better alternative is to run your application with `-Djdk.util.jar.enableMultiRelease=false`. This is effectively what was happening in Spring Boot 2.x due to the way that Tomcat used to handle the `java.lang.IllegalStateException`

Comment: Thanks, I added your sugestion. Which library is the culprit, tomcat-embed-jasper?

Comment: The change in Tomcat's exception handling is due to a change in `org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.JarFileUrlJar`. It's part of `tomcat-embed-core`. It's called by code in `tomcat-embed-jasper` when scanning for tag libraries.